# LinkedIn integration Android mobile SDK email id not fetching

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I Agreed OAuth User Agreement:

Default Scope:
    r_basicprofile
    r_fullprofile

***URL***

```
private static final String host = "api.linkedin.com"; 
private static final String PROTECTED_URL_GET_CURRENT_USER_PROFILE = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,industry)";
```

Rest all i am getting except email address.? Any one know why?

Comment: @Stella you got any solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to specify email permission when you build a scope `Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS`

eg.

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE,Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```

linkedin urls

```
private static final String host = "api.linkedin.com";
private static final String topCardUrl = "https://" + host
            + "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,picture-url,email-address,picture-urls::(original))";
```

this is login code

```
 public void login() {
        LISessionManager sessionManager = LISessionManager
                .getInstance(context);
        LISession session = sessionManager.getSession();
        boolean accessTokenValid = session.isValid();

        if (accessTokenValid) {
            getProfile();
        } else {

            LISessionManager.getInstance(context).init(context, buildScope(),
                    new AuthListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthSuccess() {
                            loginSuccess(LISessionManager.getInstance(context)
                                    .getSession().getAccessToken());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                            loginFailed(error);

                        }
                    }, true);
        }
    }
```

this is for getting profile

```
public void getProfile() {
        APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(context);
        apiHelper.getRequest(context, topCardUrl, new ApiListener() {
            @Override
            public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse s) {
                onProfileSuccess(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
                onProfileError(error);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It helped me, Thanks.

Comment: loginSuccess(LISessionManager.getInstance(context)
                                    .getSession().getAccessToken());
what we need here?

Comment: onProfileSuccess(s); this too

Comment: @PrithivDharmaraj its just a callback nothing else, you can replace loginSuccess  method with getProfile method.

Comment: ok, thank you. and one more doubt user has LinkedIn app  that time only that process working.suppose user don't have LinkedIn app means it's not opening and its opening play store and ask to download the Linkedin app. I can open like FB.(user have app means default its open that app otherwise its open one default login page)

Comment: @PrithivDharmaraj yes linkedin sdk needs app installed. I didn't find more on that.